# Removing text infant of an observation in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I have a Variable which looks like this

```
    ZIPCODE
    1
    2
    3
    NYC 4
    NYC 5
    NYC 6
```

I want to remove only the NYC in front of my observation and only keep the number behind it, without changing the observations without the NYC in front. Is there a way which allows me to do this?

Comment: `x$ZIPCODE <- sub("^NYC\\s*", "", x$ZIPCODE)` (where `x` is the name of the dataframe). If that is "sufficient" (that's the only thing non-numeric in the column), then if you want to subsequently convert to a number, use `as.integer` or `as.numeric` (depending on your data).

Comment: Since you tagged this as [tag:tidyverse], then (1) you should probably be working with tibbles, and that is not one; (2) you'd use `... %>% mutate(ZIPCODE = sub("^NYC\\s*", "", ZIPCODE))`.

Comment: Thank you ver much!!!

Comment: What does the ^ and \\s* stand for?

Comment: `^` is beginning of the string. `\s` (in general regex) is whitespace, the extra backslash is for R (before R-4.0, or R-4 and not-raw strings). The `*` is "0 or more" (alternatively, `+` would be "1 or more"; both `*` and `+` must follow something, meaning "0/1 or more of that character/class"; not to be confused with file-globbing, where `?` is one character and `*` is 0 or more characters). I suggest a regex cheatsheet or tutorial, such as https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/strings.pdf (page 2)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `parse_number`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
   mutate(ZIPCODE = readr::parse_number(ZIPCODE))
```